# React Native: Conditionally Render Components

Tags: react-native

I've searched this question and found a solution that said to conditionally render based on the state as follows:

```
  render() {

    const content = this.state.isReady ? <Home/> : <Splash/>;

    return (
      {content}
    );
  }
```

However, I keep getting an `Invariant Violation: Objects are not valid a React child (found object with keys {content}.`

Comment: `return content;`

Answer (score 0):

your make typo, you returned `Object`, instead use between JSX elements:

```
const Ready = () => <div>Ready</div>
const NotReady = () => <div>NotReady</div>

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      isReady: false
    };
  }

  render() {
    const content=this.state.isReady ? <Ready /> : <NotReady />
    return (
      <div>
        {content}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use simple if else instead of ternary expression because sometimes ternary operators "return" whatever's inside and can't execute blocks of code.

```
if (this.state.isReady) {
    return <Home />
} else {
    return <Splash />
}
```